# Parsing specific texts using Jsoup

Tags: android, parsing, html-parsing, jsoup, android-file

I have a `cities.txt` file placed in my res/raw folder. Inside it contains the following.

```
<div class="state">Alabama</div>
<ul><li><a href="http://auburn.org">auburn</a></li>
<li><a href="http://bham.org">birmingham</a></li> </ul>

<div class="state">Alaska</div>
<ul><li><a href="http://anchorage.org">anchorage</a></li>
<li><a href="http://fairbanks.org">fairbanks</a></li></ul>

<div class="state">Arizona</div>
<ul><li><a href="http://flagstaff.org">flagstaff</a></li>
<li><a href="http://mohave.org">mohave county</a></li></ul>
```

I want to grab the cities for the **state Alabama** and display it on a ListView. The ouput should be like this.

**auburn**

**birmingham**

My current code grabs all the six cities and displays them on the ListView instead. This is my code.

```
package com.example.readfile;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Cities extends Activity {

    ListView listUSCities;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.city_layout);
        listUSCities = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listcities);

        new MyTask().execute();

    }

    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

        ArrayList<String> arr_linkText = new ArrayList<String>();

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {

            Document doc;

            try {
                Resources res = getResources();
                InputStream in_s = res.openRawResource(R.raw.cities);

                byte[] b = new byte[in_s.available()];
                in_s.read(b);

                // Parsing using Jsoup starts here
                doc = Jsoup.parse(new String(b));

                // Parsing the states
                Elements links = doc.select("div");
                for (Element link : links) {
                    if (link.text().contains("Alabama")) {

                        // Extracting the cities
                        Elements cities = doc.select("a");
                        for (Element city : cities) {
                            arr_linkText.add(city.text());
                        }

                    }

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return arr_linkText; // << retrun ArrayList from here
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    Cities.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    android.R.id.text1);
            for (String temp_result : result) {

                adapter.add(temp_result);
            }
            listUSCities.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }

}
```

**How can I extract the cities only for that specified state?**

**How do I stop parsing the file after I extracted the cities to optimize speed?**

The actual `cities.txt`contains more information, I only  provided a sample. I will appreciate your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an odd structure for an HTML document.  The `<div>` is used just for the header, and the list is off by itself.  Seeing as you trimmed the actual document, this may or may not work.  The elements you are after are in the `ul` element following your `div`, so you need to go to the next sibling and search there.  This will only work if there are no other elements between your `div` and `ul` elements.

```
Elements links = doc.select("div");
for (Element link : links) {
    if (link.text().contains("Alabama")) {
       // Extracting the cities in the list that is next in the DOM
        Elements cities = link.nextElementSibling().select("a");
        for (Element city : cities) {

            arr_linkText.add(city.text());
        }
}
```

}

Comment: This made it work. I had to trim the actual document to make parsing faster. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Glad it worked.  Trimming for faster processing is a good plan.  I just wanted to be clear that if the answer was based on the structure of the sample!

Answer (score 1):

```
// Parsing the states
                Elements links = doc.select("div");
                for (Element link : links) {
                    if (link.text().contains("Alabama")) {

        // Extracting the cities
        Elements cities = link.select("a");//<- 'doc' is the whole doc, link is your state.
        for (Element city : cities) {
            arr_linkText.add(city.text());
        }
        break;//breaks off the loop, since you have found what you want.

    }

}
```

Comment: It still extracts all the cities, I just need the cities in Alabama. I think you answered my second question.

Comment: Updated. Have a look at it.

Comment: This time it did not extract anything. The ListView is empty.

Comment: Elements cities = link.select("a"); Are you sure that this line doesn't work? is it not returning any results when selecting? try link.select("ui li a");

Comment: Yeah even with "ui li a" it did not work .. I would get no results. The above answer by iagreen made it worked. Thank you though!